# Grails Data Source URL for Oracle Database that uses TNS

Tags: oracle, grails, connection-string, tnsnames, tns

I'm writing a Groovy/Grails application that will be connecting to an Oracle database that uses TNS names for resolving the actual host.  The problem I'm running into is trying to figure out the connection string (called the url in the DataSource.groovy file).  I've tried Googling examples, but all the examples I've found so far include the host name, something that I want to avoid since I've been told that this database uses TNS names so that the host can change and the various apps that connect to it won't need to be updated with the new host name.

If someone can provide an example or link that would help me create a connection string using the following details that would be much appreciated.

TNS name: TEST

Username: User

Password: Password

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633599/using-pure-tnsnames-rather-than-host-based-database-connections-in-oracle-jdevel

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the host name and the port of the machine that has the listener at least. The actual DB host will be in the TNS file and can be changed without having to change the url string.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:User/Password@//myhost:1521/TEST
```

Comment: Any way of finding out which machine is the listener (ie: would Oracle SQL Developer or some other app tell me)?

Comment: If you are able to connect from Oracle SQL Developer then you should already know the machine name. How are you connecting? If it's the same machine your hosting your app in then just use `localhost` otherswise you can get it from the connection string.

Comment: In SQL Developer I simply choose a TNS connection and put in the TNS name, my username and password.  Never do I specify a host name.  SQL Developer figures out the host name itself from the TNS name.  Sort of like what the tnsping utility does.  That's what I'm trying to reproduce.

Comment: Have you tried using the above connection string with `localhost` as the host name?

Comment: Local host won't work cause the database is not hosted locally.  It's on a seperate server.